# REST - how to view response, but filter it on an SQL table join

Tags: javascript, sql-server, rest, arcgis

One of our clients is providing us with an ArcGIS REST Endpoint. Using this, we can view maps.

However, we have an SQL table which has data related to this. The client's data (which is spatial) contains an ID field, and our data (which isn't spatial) also contains an ID field. They can be linked together on a one-to-one basis.

But we need this so that we can filter on our data, and see everything that would match that criteria with this join.

As an example, there is this REST endpoint from ArcGIS:

http://sampleserver3.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Petroleum/KSFields/FeatureServer/

Or, to see it as a map:

http://www.arcgis.com/home/webmap/viewer.html?url=http://sampleserver3.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Petroleum/KSFields/FeatureServer/

The example has a field in it called "Field Status" which would be a good one to filter on (though it's not a unique value).

Sorry it's so vague, I've tried many different solutions but come up short.

Comment: You only have a few options, depending on what parameters the API provides. You either can derive a list of IDs matching your criteria and submit them in your request, or you retrieve all of the data that might be relevant and filter it after the fact (the response gets stored in a temporary SQL table and gets filtered after retrieval), or you make multiple calls to the REST service. Without relevant info on the interface and return values, that's really all I can give you.

Comment: That's what I thought. We're looking at other solutions too.